# Draft.js невозможно выделить/удалить картинку

Tags: reactjs

Необходимо парсить html в draft.js
Но картинки выделяются и все равно не удаляются. так-же если поставить курсор после картинки ее тоже нельзя удалить

Код декоратора для картинки

```
function findImageEntities(contentBlock, callback, contentState) {
contentBlock.findEntityRanges(
    (character) => {
        const entityKey = character.getEntity();
        if(entityKey !== null && contentState.getEntity(entityKey).getType() === 'IMAGE'){
            console.log('props');
        }
        return (
            entityKey !== null &&
            contentState.getEntity(entityKey).getType() === 'IMAGE'
        );
    },
    callback
);}

const Image = (props) => {
const {
    height,
    src,
    width,
} = props.contentState.getEntity(props.entityKey).getData();
return (
        <img src={src} />
);};
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте картинку в качестве background-image для тега `<span>`, тогда Draft.js будет воспринимать содержимое как редактируемый контент.